# Some Normal mode mappings not working in vim9 anymore

Tags: key-bindings, gvim, vim9

I have the following in my configuration:

```
nnoremap µ iii
nnoremap ° ioo
```

I'm using gvim, on Windows 10, using an azerty keyboard (so `µ` is `<S-*>` and `°` is `<S-)`).

The mappings work in vim8, but after upgrading to vim9, even though I can still see these mappings using

```
nnoremap µ
nnoremap °
```

Pressing `µ` or `°` in normal mode triggers vim's bell instead of my mappings.

Did vim9 change something in that area?

Comment: Nothing related to what you are trying to do changed and your mappings work fine. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @romainl I have the uttermost respect for you, thank you for your input. I did try a lot of things elsewhere but to no avail. Vivan De Smedt's suggestion worked, so maybe there is a time component in the detection of the mapping. It might explain why on some computers it works (yours?) while on some others it does not (mine?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Vim is not precise in the mapping, in particular you have to specify the key modifier and the resulting character.

I believe you should do with Vim-9:

```
nnoremap <S-°> iii
nnoremap <S-µ> ioo
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks!